# Sublime Text Plugin - Add a scope(or colour) to a region

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to create a plugin for SublimeText that will check a file path and highlights it in the editor if it is invalid. While I think I have the correct way of checking if the filepath exists or not, I have no idea how to go about setting a scope(or other text highlight ie, turn it red) for that region. for example

* file * 
**./././thisisaninvalidfilepath**
* rest_of_file *

Cheers in advance,
Chris

Comment: Anyone? I cant seem to find any documentation on changing scope?

Comment: Check out the [Color Highlighter](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter) plugin, it seems to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `view.add_region`. See the method documentation here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View

The bad part is that you can't use any color, just pre-defined scopes. The plugin mentioned above, `ColorHighlighter`, works by duplicating your current scheme and adding the needed colors (corresponding to the hexadecimal strings) into a "fake" scheme, then loading this fake scheme.

This is a basic flaw in Sublime's API, IMO.